# ray.tune.run stuck before starting training infinitely

Tags: ray

I use `ray.tune.run` to train a customized gym model by using `rllib` after `ray.init(num_cpus=2)`

I do not need to search hyperparameters so I give parameters in model config specific values. But `tune.run` seems still stuck in parameter searching infinitely with repeatedly outputting in terminal the following results

```
== Status ==
Current time: 2021-12-15 10:14:37 (running for 00:22:40.96)
Memory usage on this node: 17.1/62.7 GiB
Using FIFO scheduling algorithm.
Resources requested: 1.0/2 CPUs, 1.0/1 GPUs, 0.0/36.44 GiB heap, 0.0/18.22 GiB objects
Result logdir: /
Number of trials: 1/1 (1 RUNNING)
+---------------------------+----------+-----------------------+
| Trial name                | status   | loc                   |
|---------------------------+----------+-----------------------|
| PPO_sim-v0_a3b49_00000    | RUNNING  | 192.168.11.86:1869965 |
+---------------------------+----------+-----------------------+
```

I tried to use ray.init() and it can start training but return `nan` reward for all iters.

And then I changed nothing and re-call `ray.tune.run`, it is again stuck in searching with above Status information.

I have no idea why this happens even I don't specify hyperparameter searching.
So can anyone help me with this problem?

Appreciate any help about this.

Comment: Hi! I am exactly in the same case, did you manage to find a solution?